# Power-Query and Power BI How to create a measure and union it back to the original data-set

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Wondering how we create a measure based on a data-set, then union it back to the original data-set ?

May be it make it easier to view the problem visually, so i have created the picture below.

[image]

P.S. Somehow i have to do it in this way in regardless of previousday OR related function

thanks

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom column to calculate the comparison volume by looking up the volume on the last date before the current row's date for that category value. Remove the `Volume` column, rename the `CalcType` from "Individual" to "Comparison" and then append that table to your original table.

Here's what the M code would look like.

```
let
    Source = <Insert Source Here>,
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"Date", type date}, {"Category", type text},
         {"CalcType", type text}, {"Volume", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Comparison", each
        try Table.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type",
            (C) => C[Date] < [Date] and C[Category] = [Category]), "Date")[Volume]
        otherwise null, Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Volume"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Comparison","Volume"}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns",
        "Individual","Comparison",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"CalcType"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Value", each ([Volume] <> null)),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", #"Filtered Rows"})
in
    #"Appended Query"
```